# Join same column from multiple tables

Tags: sql, match, union, teradata

Below is my current code. I'm not sure what the best way is to amend this to give me the results I need.

```
SELECT
T1.SC,
T1.AN,
T1.DOFS_DATE,
T2.M_ID,
T3.OPDT,
T4.MARKER,
T5.E_DTE,
T5.E_TME,
T5.E_PST_DTE,  
T5.E_AMT,
T5.E_NAR_O,
T5.E_NAR_T
FROM E_Base.AR_MyTable T1

LEFT JOIN  E_Base.Translation T2
ON T1.SC = T2.SC
AND T1.AN = T2.AN

LEFT JOIN E_Base.BA T3
ON T2.M_ID = T3.M_ID

LEFT JOIN E_Base.APF T4
ON T3.M_ID = T4.M_ ID
AND MARKER = 54

LEFT JOIN U_DB.TEH_201804 T5
ON T2.M_ID = T5.M_ID
AND T1.DOFS_DATE = T5.E_PST_DTE

QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.M_ID ORDER BY T2.ID_END_DATE DESC, T3.E_END_DATE DESC) = 1
```

The above code works. However, it is the final left join on T5 where I need help.

In T1 each M_ID has assigned it's own DOFS_DATE that could be any date within the year and I want the data from T5 U_DB.TEH_201804 for the matching date. However, 5 U_DB.TEH_201804 relates to only April 2018. There are 12 tables with the same database (201804, 201805, 201806 etc) that all have the exact same columns but relate to a different month within the year.

Ideally, I want to left join the columns from T5 once but search all 12 tables within the database to bring back the data where the dates correspond.

I was thinking UNION but am unsure how to work this in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have 12 tables with *exact same columns but relate to a different month within the year* instead of one table (which could be partitioned by month)?

Comment: It's beyond me. All I know is at month end the data is archived into a separate table. Makes my life much more difficult!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change you code related to table t5 wuth a left join on a subquery that select the union all for all the bale you need ...... (i have named the subquery  TT)

```
    SELECT
    T1.SC,
    T1.AN,
    T1.DOFS_DATE,
    T2.M_ID,
    T3.OPDT,
    T4.MARKER,
    TT.E_DTE,
    TT.E_TME,
    TT.E_PST_DTE,  
    TT.E_AMT,
    TT.E_NAR_O,
    TT.E_NAR_T
    FROM E_Base.AR_MyTable T1

    LEFT JOIN  E_Base.Translation T2
    ON T1.SC = T2.SC
    AND T1.AN = T2.AN

    LEFT JOIN E_Base.BA T3
    ON T2.M_ID = T3.M_ID

    LEFT JOIN E_Base.APF T4
    ON T3.M_ID = T4.M_ ID
    AND MARKER = 54

    LEFT  JOIN (
                select *
                FROM U_DB.TEH_201804
                UNION ALL 
                select *
                FROM U_DB.TEH_201805
                UNION ALL 
                select *
                FROM U_DB.TEH_201806
                UNION ALL   
                select *
                FROM U_DB.TEH_201807
                UNION ALL 
                .....
            ) TT ON T2.M_ID = TT.M_ID
                AND T1.DOFS_DATE = TT.E_PST_DTE

    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.M_ID ORDER BY T2.ID_END_DATE DESC, T3.E_END_DATE DESC) = 1
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. However, when I go to run the query I get "SELECT Failed. 2646. No more spool space in myusername. Would you have any idea why this would be for this query?

Comment: could be you are involving  too many rows  and have some issue  .. googleing  for your error i have found  http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/no-more-spool-space-teradata-query-solution

Comment: Thank you! The database and tables I'm looking in are huge so maybe the query is too big for my allocation. If I search for only 6 months it runs perfectly so I'll just split it into two separate queries and merge the data together in excel after. Massively appreciate the help and quick response!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without additional details like explain and QueryLog step data.

Based on @scaisEdge answer:

You can try to move the first two joins into a Derived Table to apply the ROW_NUMBER early (possible because you do Outer Joins only):

```
SELECT
   dt.*,
   T4.MARKER,
   TT.E_DTE,
   TT.E_TME,
   TT.E_PST_DTE,  
   TT.E_AMT,
   TT.E_NAR_O,
   TT.E_NAR_T
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
      T1.SC,
      T1.AN,
      T1.DOFS_DATE,
      T2.M_ID,
      T3.OPDT
   FROM E_Base.AR_MyTable T1

   LEFT JOIN  E_Base.Translation T2
   ON T1.SC = T2.SC
   AND T1.AN = T2.AN

   LEFT JOIN E_Base.BA T3
   ON T2.M_ID = T3.M_ID

   QUALIFY Row_Number()
           Over (PARTITION BY T2.M_ID
                 ORDER BY T2.ID_END_DATE DESC, T3.E_END_DATE DESC) = 1 
 ) AS dt

LEFT JOIN E_Base.APF T4
ON dt.M_ID = T4.M_ID
AND MARKER = 54

LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM U_DB.TEH_201804
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT *
   FROM U_DB.TEH_201805
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT *
   FROM U_DB.TEH_201806
   UNION ALL   
   SELECT *
   FROM U_DB.TEH_201807
   UNION ALL 
   .....
 ) TT
ON dt.M_ID = TT.M_ID
AND dt.DOFS_DATE = TT.E_PST_DTE
```

It might also help the optimizer to provide additional info about the data ranges. Those tables should have CHECK-constraints to tell the optimizer that they contain only data from a single month, if they don't exist try adding a WHERE-condition to each Select, e.g. `WHERE E_PST_DTE BETWEEN DATE '2018-04-01' AND DATE '2018-04-30'`.

Of course, always check Explain if the plan actually changes...